# GenericTypeParameterBuilder doesn't support IsAssignableFrom

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I'm making a toy .NET language via `Reflection.Emit`, and one of the inevitable features was making a check to see if instantiations of generics met their constraints, which was simple to add, unless one constraint refers to another type parameter, such as (in C#)

```
class MyClass<T, U> where U : T {}
```

or

```
class Foo<T> {

  class Bar<U : T> {}

}
```

I've been checking constraints by means of `Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)`, but `GenericTypeParameterBuilder` overrides it to throw an `NotSupportedException`. How can I check that the type constraints are met without throwing this error?

**EDIT:**

I had the idea that I could probably solve the problem by calling `Type.MakeGenericType(Type[])`, and catching the error thrown when the types I gave it didn't match, but apparently `TypeBuilders` don't care, and it's possible to emit types that don't meet the constraints (such as `MyClass<void, int>`).

**EDIT 2:**

This is given as an answer to the request in the comments.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Demo {

  public static void Main() {
    AssemblyBuilder assembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("demo"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.ReflectionOnly);
    ModuleBuilder module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("demo");
    TypeBuilder type = module.DefineType("MyType");
    GenericTypeParameterBuilder[] @params = type.DefineGenericParameters("T", "U");
    @params[1].SetBaseTypeConstraint(@params[0]);
    Type[] args = new[] {typeof(IEnumerable<char>), typeof(string)};
    bool meetsConstraints = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      meetsConstraints &= @params[i].IsAssignableFrom(args[i]); // error is here
    }
    Console.WriteLine(meetsConstraints);
  }

}
```

Comment: What are the types are you checking in `IsAssignableFrom`?

Comment: For instance, for `class Demo<T> where T : IEnumerable<char> {...}`, `Demo<string>` checks `typeof(IEnumerable<char>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string))`.

Comment: That comparison already returns true. See [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mRWU4l).

Comment: But when one constraint refers to another, I.E. `MyClass` above, it would resolve to `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(U))`, which doesn't work because `typeof(T)` and `typeof(U)` are `GenericTypeParameterBuilder`s.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. [If I try to make a generic type with that signature, checking `IsAssignableFrom` still returns true](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YXatW2). Can you provide a [mcve] so that I can see what it is you are actually trying to do?